# Is -y redundant in apt-get update?

Tags: apt, update-manager

I'm often using `apt-get install -y` which works great.

Recently I saw a pull request where someone wanted to update `apt-get update` with `apt-get update -y`.

In my experience `apt-get update` doesn't prompt the user.

Is this [pull request](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/pull/55) redundant or are there prompt messages that can occur in `apt-get update`?

Comment: Afaik there are no prompts in `apt update` or `apt-get update`. And even on `apt dist-upgrade` I think advising `-y` is quite dangerous because it removes a last chance to reconsider the action.

Comment: @Videonauth when the commands are controlled by automated scripts no one will see the output anyways.

Comment: True, but then the user in most of the cases knows what hes is scripting there and then the command might even include `-qq`.

Comment: @Videonauth good point, here is the PR for anyone interested https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/pull/55

Comment: Also never saw any prompts for `update` .. what should you be prompted here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the `-y` option together with `update` is totally redundant, yet accepted due to the many powers `apt` and `apt-get` have.

To make that clear, `apt-get` would accept any valid global option that makes sense with the command. If you pass it anything else it would complain. (Thanks to [@Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam) for pointing this out)

On a personal note, I frown on tutorials giving the advice to run an option like `upgrade` and so on with the `-y` option, because it removes a layer of reconsideration for the user. Yet it has its purpose for scripting tasks and might then mostly go along with `-qq` which quiets all output.

Comment: I'ld usually recommend not to use `-y` at all .. but e.g. after running `sudo apt upgrade --dry-run` it's probably annoying to get through it again

Comment: @derHugo as mentioned this is part of a script. If you do `apt-get install` without `-y` in a script it just won't respond.

Comment: To clarify: apt-get would accept any valid global option that makes sense with the command. If you pass -b it would complain that "is not understood in combination with the other options."